# LTE and GTE filters do not work inside Viewset

Tags: python, django

I defined `DjangoFilterBackend` inside `filter_backends` and added (tried to) the correct definitions as shown in `filter_fields`. It does not give any error in url search but it does not give any result (as filtered) in shown URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/publicusers/?deliveredtotime__lte=50
```

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, default='undefinedusername')
    deliveredtotime = models.IntegerField(default='0')

class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_fields = { 'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your edit that I rolled back: `{'username','id', 'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte'],}` is neither a valid dictionary nor a valid set... Give Python something valid to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`filter_fields`</s> has been renamed to `filterset_fields` since [django-filter-22.1](/questions/tagged/django-filter-22.1):

```
class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_fields = {
        'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']
    }  # 🖘 not filter_fields
```

Comment: @umarbeyoglu editing a question and invalidating existing answers is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal). This answer was valid for your previous revision, please refrain from changing your question and ask a new one if you have another question.

Comment: @umarbeyoglu [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post) your initial question was a good question on its own, I rolled your edit back since it invalidated the answer. Personally I don't downvote just because of edits like that (in others words I didn't downvote your question)